# How can I concatenate(or merge) values from 2 result sets with the same PK?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I don't know if I'm being dumb here but I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this. I wrote a very long and inefficient query that does what I need, but what I WANT is a more efficient way.

I have 2 result sets that displays an ID (a PK which is generic/from the same source in both sets) and a FLAG (A - approve and V - Validate).

Result Set 1

ID    FLAG
1     V
2     V
3     V
4     V
5     V
6     V

Result Set 2

ID    FLAG
2     A
5     A
7     A
8     A

I want to "merge" these two sets to give me this output:

ID    FLAG
1     V
2     (V/A)
3     V
4     V
5     (V/A)
6     V
7     A
8     A

Neither of the 2 result sets will at any time have all the ID's to make a simple left join with a case statement on the other result set an easy solution.

I'm currently doing a union between the two sets to get ALL the ID's. Thereafter I left join the 2 result sets to get the required '(V/A)' by use of a case statement.

There must be a more efficient way but I just can't seem to figure it out now as I'm running low on amps... I need a holiday... :-/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE
         WHEN t1.FLAG IS NULL THEN t2.FLAG
         WHEN t2.FLAG IS NULL THEN t1.FLAG
         ELSE '(' || t1.FLAG || '/' || t2.FLAG || ')'
       END AS MERGED_FLAG
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    USING (ID)
  ORDER BY ID
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6798f/10).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks Bob! Seems I REALLY need a break. Appreciate thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use xmlagg. Here an exemple :

```
SELECT deptno,
       SUBSTR (REPLACE (REPLACE (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT ("x", ename)
                                 ORDER BY ename),'</x>'),'<x>','|'),2)  as concated_list
FROM emp
    GROUP BY deptno
    ORDER BY deptno;
```

Bye